# Extract in and out degrees in a graph

Tags: python, graph, vertex

I'm trying to get the value of in and out degree of a vertex in a graph. I already implemented a Graph class, but I need a function that gives me the degree value. I'm trying to do that with no networkX methods. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:

 def __init__(self):
     self._graph = defaultdict(set)
     self._weight = dict()

 def node_count(self):
     return len(self._graph)

 def neighbours(self, n):
     return iter(self._graph[n])

 def add_node(self, n):
     self._graph[n] = set()

 def remove_node(self, n):
     for n1 in self.neighbours(n):
         if n1 != n:
             self._graph[n1].remove(n)
         del self._weight[self._edge(n, n1)]
     del self._graph[n]

 def _edge(self, n1, n2):
     return (n1, n2) if n1 <= n2 else (n2, n1)

 def edge_count(self):
     return len(self._weight)

 def add_edge(self, n1, n2, w=0.0):
     self._graph[n1].add(n2)
     #self._graph[n2].add(n1)
     self._weight[self._edge(n1, n2)] = w

 def remove_edge(self, n1, n2):
     self._graph[n1].remove(n2)
     if n1 != n2:
         self._graph[n2].remove(n1)
     del self._weight[self._edge(n1, n2)]
 def get_connections(self):
     total = 0
     for w in self._weight.values():
         total += w
     return total
```

How would I write a function that return the in-degree and the out-degree from a vertex in this graph?

```
def out(self, vertex):
    return ??
def _in(self, vertex):
    return ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Your graph currently is not directed, so there's no point in in- and out-degrees.

Adapt your functions accordingly.

```py
    def add_edge(self, n1, n2, w=0.0):
        self._graph[n1].add(n2)
        # self._graph[n2].add(n1)
        self._weight[(n1, n2)] = w
```

If you want it undirected or made the adaptations, you can use `len(neighbours(node))`

With the current structure you can get indegrees by checking all nodes, but it's `O(n)`

Comment: I was using it for undirected graphs and forgot to remove this part, I'm wanting the function for an ordered graph, thanks for the remark